# How to save memory when using a trie?

Tags: c++

I came across this quesiton:
https://atcoder.jp/contests/agc047/tasks/agc047_b and my code is as follows. My solution is very similar to the editorial.

I'm confused why this has memory issues. I make 10^6 * 26 nodes in the worst case scenario. The memory limit is 1024MB which seems like much more than enough. How is memory measured for a self referential class?

Additionally, how can I salvage my code?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

#define MAXN 200005

using namespace std;

struct node {
    long long cnt;
    node *children[26];

public:
    node() {
        cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            children[i] = nullptr;
    }
};

string info[MAXN];

bool comp(string a, string b) {
    return a.length() > b.length();
}
int main() {
#ifdef orange
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
#endif
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> info[i];
    sort(info, info + n, comp);

    node *trie = new node;
    long long ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        node *curr = trie;
        for (int j = info[i].length() - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            int z = info[i][j] - 'a';
            if (curr->children[z] == nullptr)
                curr->children[z] = new node;
            curr = curr->children[z];
        }

        ans += curr->cnt;
        curr = trie;
        int first[26];
        fill(first, first + 26, info[i].length()+1);
        for (int j = 0; j < info[i].length(); j++) {
            if (first[info[i][j] - 'a'] ==info[i].length()+1)
                first[info[i][j] - 'a'] = j;
        }

        for (int j = info[i].length() - 1; j >= -1; j--) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                if (first[i] < j + 1) {
                    node *branch = curr;
                    if (branch->children[i] == nullptr)
                        branch->children[i] = new node;
                    branch = branch->children[i];
                    branch->cnt++;
                }
            }
            if(j==-1)
                break;
            int next = info[i][j] - 'a';
            if (curr->children[next] == nullptr) {
                curr->children[next] = new node;
            }
            curr = curr->children[next];
        }
    }
    cout << ans << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without relying on external links. What is the input? What is the program supposed to do? How much memory did it use when you debugged it?

Comment: Take a look at the radix-trie, it's like the regular trie but may save you a bit of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With 26 million nodes and 1024 megabytes, each node will need to be less than 40 bytes. But `sizeof(node)` is going to be at least 112 bytes, just for its members. The "self-referential" part comes from 26 pointers, each of which needs to be 4 bytes to support 1024MB.

You'll need another data structure. One solution is to have just a single `firstChild` per node, but also a `nextSibling` and a `char c`.

Comment: There's a good chance the code is 64-bit which makes it even worse at a 216 byte minimum

Comment: Quick explanation of the math: On a 32-bit system, each pointer is 4 bytes. `node *children[26]` = 26 pointers. `long long` = at least 8 bytes. Total: 26*4 + 8 = 112.